# Representing python dictionaries as matrices or csvs

Tags: python, maps, iteration, dictionary

I'm trying to get a python dictionary with the following structure:

```
>>>my_dict
>>>(i1,j1):{c1:1,c2:3,c3:4},(i2,j2):{c1:1,c2:1,c3:1}...
```

What I would like to do is get the key (i,j) and the r1,r2,r3.rn in a matrix or some sort of table used for visulization. So  the table representation would look like this.

```
       c1  c2  c3 ...rN
i1,j1   1   3  4        
i2,j2   1   1  1     
iN,jN
```

Basically I want my primary keys on the rows and the keys of my value (which is another dictionary) on the column. Then easily map the keys to a column and row value.

I'm being really specific, and this is just one example. I'm actually confused as to what i'm looking for. I have to do this many times, Is their an easy way to map dictionaries to a table like this? Is there some module I should be looking for?

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: Is this a question about how to print the data structure you have proposed? Or about actually storing the data?

Answer (score 2):

```
dic={('i1','j1'):{'c1':1,'c2':3,'c3':4},('i2','j2'):{'c1':1,'c2':1,'c3':1}}
header=list(max(dic.values()))
print '\t',
print "  ".join(sorted(header))
for x in dic:
    print ",".join(x)+'\t',
    for y in sorted(dic[x]):
        print str(dic[x][y])+"  ",
    print
```

**output:**

```
        c1  c2  c3
i1,j1   1   3   4  
i2,j2   1   1   1
```

to write this to a file, try this:

```
with open('data.txt','w') as f:
    dic={('i1','j1'):{'c1':1,'c2':3,'c3':4},('i2','j2'):{'c1':1,'c2':1,'c3':1}}
    header=list(max(dic.values()))
    f.write('\t')
    f.write("  ".join(sorted(header))+'\n')
    for x in dic:
        f.write(",".join(x)+'\t')
        for y in sorted(dic[x]):
            f.write(str(dic[x][y])+"  ")
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Right on, this is the kind of answer that gets it done! I just need to think about data structures better. For example, I didn't know you could sort a dict.

Comment: This is close, it's not calculating all the values right, but I'll figure it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ 
    'primary_key1': [{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data}]},
    'primary_key2': [{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data}]} 
     ...
    'primary_keyN': [{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data}]}
}
```

So Now you can retrieve them back using PK and if you have a keys you can store them in dict with duplicate Keys like :

```
'primary_key1': [{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data},{key: data}]
```

or else if you hava always unique key for value then do nesting:

```
'primary_key1': {key: data, key: data, key: data},
```

or Else only data then :

```
'primary_key1': [data, data, data],
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am not sure how this answer addresses the question. It looks like the OP already has a data structure that functions.

Comment: jdi he ashed need to store them in table format and their can be several ways you can target it, instead of the Complex loop that is proposed by lady Ashvini in above comment,

Comment: Did you just call @AshwiniChaudhary a lady? lol. Anyways. My point was that the data structure the OP had works perfectly fine and supports the multi-key tuple format. Having the value be a list would require needing to access via index which might be completely unrelated to the desired column key.